# How to increase inter database query execution speed in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using this inter-database query as shown below, but it works very slowly. Is there any other way to make the this query execute faster?

```
update [CCAVENUE].[dbo].[ARInvoice] 
set Post_Flag = 'Y',
    sap_docentry = (select DocEntry 
                    from [SAPCCAVENU].[dbo].[oinv] 
                    where U_Invoice_No = Invoice_no SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS)
```

Comment: Both table are with different collation ?

Comment: You could create a calculated column in that pre-casts the Invoice_No to the correct collation then create an index on it

Comment: You'd have to do some analysis on the where the time is being spent in order to improve the performance. There isn't enough information to do anything other than guess as it stands.

Comment: Does the updated table have a poorly written trigger?

Comment: (1) Changing the collation pretty much kills any optimization on the subquery.  (2) Without knowing what column comes from which table, it is pretty hard to make any suggestions.  **Qualify all column references!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
UPDATE [CCAVENUE].[dbo].[ARInvoice] SET Post_Flag='Y', sap_docentry=DocEntry
    FROM [CCAVENUE].[dbo].[ARInvoice]
    JOIN [SAPCCAVENU].[dbo].[oinv] ON U_Invoice_No=Invoice_no
```

Comment: Join is faster than subquery. May be some other process uses this table.

Answer (score 0):

If the both tables are only same server then you can try below

```
UPDATE AR
SET AR.Post_Flag='Y',
    AR.sap_docentry = OI.DocEntry
FROM [CCAVENUE].[dbo].[ARInvoice] AR
INNER JOIN [SAPCCAVENU].[dbo].[oinv] OI 
    ON U_Invoice_No=Invoice_no collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
```

If both tables are on different database server then you should try below

```
SELECT DISTINCT U_Invoice_No, DocEntry INTO #tmp_oinv FROM [SAPCCAVENU].[dbo].[oinv]

UPDATE AR
SET AR.Post_Flag='Y',
    AR.sap_docentry = OI.DocEntry
FROM [CCAVENUE].[dbo].[ARInvoice] AR
INNER JOIN #tmp_oinv OI 
    ON U_Invoice_No=Invoice_no collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
```

Comment: OP query is accessing two different `database` not `database server`

Comment: then you should try the first query.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH t2 AS
(
   select DocEntry 
   from [SAPCCAVENU].[dbo].[oinv] 
   where U_Invoice_No = Invoice_no SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
)    
UPDATE t1
  SET t1.Post_Flag = 'Y',
  t1.sap_docentry=t2.DocEntry
  FROM [CCAVENUE].[dbo].[ARInvoice]  AS t1
  JOIN t2
  ON U_Invoice_No=Invoice_no;
```

Note:

Try this query. Here I'm updating the data using a CTE i.e. Common Table Expression.